# python thread safe mutable object copy

Tags: python, thread-safety, copy, deep-copy

Is [python's `copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module thread safe?

If not, how should I copy\deepcopy mutable objects in a thread-safe manner in python?

Comment: isn't everything (more ore less) thread safe in python... that's why the GIL keeps locking up...

Answer (score 14):

Python's [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) protects bytecodes, not Python statements (see [short](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/WhatTheGILProtects) or [long](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf) explanations). As both `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` are implemented in python, they are certainly more than a single bytecode, so no, **they are not thread safe!**

If you must work with multiple threads, and there are many cases you should such as having IO dedicated threads, do what must be done - use [`threading.Lock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock). Notice you can [use the elegant with statement with the lock object](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html).

Comment: wrong answer. Python collections are thread-safe. They themselves don't go corrupt, but their data may.